# Iterate through multidimensional associative array in PHP when every key is a string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array like:

```
$fruits = array(
  'citrus' => array(
    'fruit one' => 'orange',
    'fruit two' => 'lime',
  ),
  'melon' => array(
    'fruit one' => 'honeydew',
    'fruit two' => 'cantalope',
  ),
  'berry' => array(
    'fruit one' => 'raspberry',
    'fruit two' => 'strawberry',
  ),
  'apple' => array(
    'fruit one' => 'granny smith',
    'fruit two' => 'fuji',
  )

);
```

I want to be able to access slices of it, like `echo $fruits[0]['fruit one'];` so that I can create a for loop to get at specific groups of the array. By that I mean, I would ideally be able to do something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++)
  echo $fruit[$i]['fruit one'];

// Then some other code

for($i = 2; $i <= 3; $i++)
  echo $fruit[$i]['fruit one'];
```

Of course I can't do that since every key is a string. Is there a simple solution to this or did I just code this dumbly?

**Edit**: I made the array longer to fully demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Tomulent, does Ben's answer below satisfy you? It allows you to loop through every fruit in every fruit group.  If that's not what you want (I couldn't tell from the OP), please rephrase what you're looking for or describe the desired output better.

Comment: I edited the original, I hope that makes it more clear. My real array has 40 arrays inside it. I need to get at a range of them at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_slice` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)) was made just for this.

For the first 2 fruit groups:

```
foreach(array_slice($fruits,0,2) as $fruitGroup) echo $fruitGroup['fruit one'];
```

For the next 2 fruit groups:

```
foreach(array_slice($fruits,2,2) as $fruitGroup) echo $fruitGroup['fruit one'];
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/XgdSB)

This has the benefit of simplicity (over Chrys' solution), and of not destroying the original keys from your array.

Comment: Switched my accepted answer since this is the most simple. Chrys's can be done without destroying the keys but this requires much less code. Thanks! You both taught me something today!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( $fruits AS $fruit ) {
  foreach ( $fruit AS $subFruit ) {
    // insert code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceKeys(&$array)
{
    $ptr = null;
    foreach ($array as $values) {
        $ptr[] = $values;
    }
    $array = $ptr;
}

$fruits = array(
  'citrus' => array(
    'fruit one' => 'orange',
    'fruit two' => 'lime',
  ),
  'melon' => array(
    'fruit one' => 'honeydew',
    'fruit two' => 'cantalope',
  )
);


replaceKeys($fruits);

var_dump($fruits[0]['fruit one']);

//Output: orange
```

Comment: Chrys you don't actually need `$i`.  Just add values with `$ptr[]=$values` and PHP will auto-increment keys for you.